# Postgres database JSON file import

Tags: json, postgresql

Is there any option to insert data from a large JSON file containing arrays of JSON objects into matching columns in my Postgres database.

I have a JSON file containing my arrays of JSON objects and I have a Postgres database table with matching column names as in the JSON response. I wanted to import the JSON response directly into my database so that the corresponding values get inserted into columns that matches the keys in the response.